# Netlogo reduce polynomial example

Tags: netlogo, reduce

In the Netlogo dictionary for "reduce" they show an example with one "+" operator

```
reduce [?1 + ?2] [1 2 3 4]
```

which they expand as equivalent to (((1 + 2) + 3) + 4).

Later they give this example:

```
;; evaluate the polynomial, with given coefficients, at x
to-report evaluate-polynomial [coefficients x]
  report reduce [(x * ?1) + ?2] coefficients
end

;; evaluate 3x^2 + 2x + 1 at x = 4
show evaluate-polynomial [3 2 1] 4
=> 57
```

What is the equivalent expansion (using parentheses) for that evaluation?

Comment: It may be worth noting that this left to right reduction assumes a traditional coefficient representation of a polynomial.  The modern representation is reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
observer> show (4 * ((4 * 3) + 2)) + 1
observer: 57
```

The key to understand it is to do it step by step. `reduce` starts by taking the first two elements of the list and plugging them into `?1` and `?2`, so

```
(x * ?1) + ?2
```

becomes

```
(x * 3) + 2
```

That whole expression then becomes `?1`, and the last element of the list, `1`, becomes `?2`. Replacing `?1` and `?2` in the initial expression again, we get:

```
(x * ((x * 3) + 2)) + 1
```

All that's left is to replace `x` with `4`:

```
(4 * ((4 * 3) + 2)) + 1
```